# Twitter Bootstrap Slider default values

Tags: jquery, python, twitter-bootstrap, bottle

I am using [this library](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/) for Bootstrap Sliders.

Here is the input on my form

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="weeks" class="col-md-3 control-label">Weeks</label>
  <input name='weeks' id="weeks" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="int" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="4" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="{{weeks}}"/>
</div>
```

Here is the code from Python Bottle:

```
return bottle.template("weeks.html",weeks=0)
```

and here how I handle the post:

```
weeks = bottle.request.forms.get("weeks")
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script>
   $('#weeks').slider({
      formater: function(value) {
      return 'Current value: ' + value;
      }
    });
</script>
```

When the page load, I set the variable weeks with 0. If I move the slider, when I submit the form, I get the right value. But, if I keep the slider in default, then on submit, I get the value None on weeks.

Comment: can you post the javascript, and where you make the `slider()` call?

Answer (score 2):

Set the initial value in the HTML, too.

```
<input type="text" class="slider" value="25" id="threshold" name="threshold">
```

In addition to

```
$('.slider').slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 250,
    step: 25,
    orientation: 'horizontal',
    value: 25,
    selection: 'before',
    tooltip: 'show'
})
```